# Multiple Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

I need to put 2 NavigationBars. The second will be below the first one.

My idea is:

In the first navigation bar have the navigation buttons and in the second have only a label centered.

The rest is a UITableView controller. When the users scroll, the content hide below the navigation bars.

[image]

Comment: why you are not adding UIview bellow the navigationbar in your viewcontroller?

Comment: Because when I scroll the tableview content, its not hide.

Comment: You can't have two UINavigationController's onscreen at once. You will need to create the lower view yourself.  It looks like you could use a UISegmentedControl or just create a UIView with a couple of buttons

Comment: you can add custom view, and manage it's height in scroll view delegate

Answer (score 2):

Paulw11 was right, you probably should create custom view, add a couple of buttons to it and attach it to the bottom of navigation bar using AutoLayout. If you need to hide this view when user scrolls, you can implement `func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)` method in your `UITableViewController` and change it's `alpha` to zero.